# Cannot use strings of resource file in Cordova Android Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, resource-file

I have created a custom plugin for cordova android and I want to use a resource-file. Therefore I have added the following tag to the plugin
`<resource-file src="src/android/res/values/strings.xml" target="res/values/strings.xml" />`

However, this will lead to the following error when building for android:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of null
>       at android_parser.update_from_config (C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Roaming\npm\
>   node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\metadata\android_parse
>   r.js:209:51) 
>   ERROR running one or more of the platforms: TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of null

The build is succesful when I remove the resource-file tag from *plugin.xml*. Nevertheless, I need those strings.

Does anyone know any solution or alternative to fix this problem? I found a similar problem here, unfortunately without any solution documented:

[phonegap build android; not able to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649344/phonegap-build-android-not-able-to-build)

Thanks.

Comment: res/values/strings.xml is an android project file, I'm not sure if you can replace it with your own file. Try using a different name.

Comment: jcesarmobile's s the solution to this problem, worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting strings in your plugin.xml like this:

```
<config-file target="res/values/strings.xml" parent="/*">
    <string name="mystringname">MyStringValue</string>
</config-file>
```